# Trying to Insert scraped date into PHPmyAdmin using Python

Tags: python, sql, web-scraping, sql-insert

I am trying to save data I have scraped using python from an api, into a sql database in PHPMyadmin. I have spent practically all day watching videos and reading trying to figure this out. Help would be appreciated.

```
import mysql.connector

mysql = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user = "root",
password = "",
database = "jpfl"
)

boxes = basket.boxes
box= boxes[0]

for box in boxes[0:9]:

    listid = box.listid
    price = box.price
    item = box.item

    mycursor = mysql.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO 'boxinfo' ('id', 'price', 'item') VALUES (%s,%s,%S)"

    val = (listid, price, item)

    mycursor.execute(sql,val)
    mysql.commit();

    print("data is saved")
```

When I use this code, and insert manual data it works. I haven't figured out how to save the data saved to variables.

Any help, or direction to resources that could help me figure this out is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: do you get any error message when you use variables ? Show this error in question. What do you have in variables?  Maybe they are empty. Did you use `print()` to check what you have in variables?

Comment: you have upper `%S` in SQL and maybe this is problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I goofed. Forgot to clear my table, and had a test entry that had a duplicate in the primary key. Thanks for the help y'all!